# Delphi: One procedure to change all the fields of a record?

Tags: delphi, record, procedure

I have a record like this:

```
Tcustomer=record
  Name: string;
  IDNumber: Integer;
  IsMarried: boolean;
end;
```

And I have a `TCustomers_Manager` class that stores a list of all the customers. Is it possible to have a procedure like this:

```
Procedure ChangeCustomer(CustomerIndex: integer; field: string; value);
```

That sets the value for that specific field. For example:

```
ChangeCustomer(1, 'Name','John');
```

How can I implement this?

Update: To clarify, my question is basically in 2 parts:

1) How can I map the field name (in string) to the actual field in record?

2) Is it possible to pass a value that has different types? Or should I pass a single type and type cast it (like passing a string and then using `strtoint()`)

Comment: Yes you can do this in the most recent
versions of Delphi using run time type
information. However, it's not always
such a great idea to abandon the static
type system. Are you sure you need to
do this?

Comment: Which "specific field" do you mean? You have to identify your costomers. Do you use the IDNumber for that? Is this IDNumber unique? ChangeCustomer has to know which customer to change. You need also an "AddCustomer". What do you mean with "List of customers"? TList or an array? I would use a small database (maybe in memory) to accomplish your task.

Comment: @Andreas: Please... This is just the part of the code I have a question in, not the whole project!! I have a TList<TCustomer> in my class. I will pass the customer index in ChangeCustomer. I obviously have AddCustomer() procedure. And no, this is too simple to use a DB for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use TClientDataSet.

1. Create TClientDataSet with fields ID, Name, etc.
2. Open Dataset, Fill with InsertRecord or Insert/Post
3. Find Record with Locate
4. Use FieldByName('FieldName').Value to access to or change data

Or you can take any MemoryDataSet component and use it in same way.

Second way is to convert record to class, declare Fields as published and use SetPropValue.

If you want to pass any Value you can use Variant. But you have to check types before assign.

Comment: The second way is just exactly what I was looking for. 'Variant' for value and 'SetPropValue' for changing the property values using their names. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ironically the question is worded to be about RTTI from records to disk, and the thing the OP really wants is a dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You could, for example, do this (assuming `lst: TList<TCustomer>` as you said in a comment):

```
Procedure ChangeCustomer(index: integer; i: byte; value: variant)
begin
    case (i) of
        0: lst[index].Name := value;
        1: lst[index].IDNumber := value;
        2: lst[index].IsMarried := value;
    end;
end;
```

You could use a type (or enum) in place of `i: byte`.
I dont't use Delphi from long time, so take my example as an *idea*, not like a Delphi app!!

Comment: Why downvote? Leave a comment to explain, so I can understand and correct if necessary, please!!!

Comment: The idea is OK, but how does ChangeCustomer know which record is to change? The whole concept is incomplete...

Comment: It is a bad idea. For 2 reasons: 1) It may work for a record with 3 fields, but what about 30 fields? It will be a mess. 2) Type of the value is different for each field. What is the type of the value in your procedure definition (in the arguments)?

Comment: @flom you've got to deal with the issue of the type of value too. What's your plan?

Comment: @Andreas, @David: you're right, thanks for pointing out problems. I wrote just an idea, not the whole code. Anyway, I edited my post to reflect your suggestions... hope now it's better...

Comment: @Flom, it works just fine with 30 fields *if* you use an enum (as suggested by Marco); The definition of `value` is slightly off, I assume Marco wanted `const value`, ie, an untyped parameter. But I'd personally use a `Variant`, not an untyped param, for better runtime error checking.

Comment: @Cosmin: using 'Variant' is a good idea. I haven't thought about it. @Marco: I don't fancy using 'case' like that. I go with the SetPropValue() that George suggested. It is way more simple to use. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Flom, `SetPropValue` only works for classes, not for records. It does it's stuff using RTTI. You can write your own variant that also works with records, since Delphi 2010+ RTTI is also generated for records (you mentioned you're using a `TList<>`, so you're on Delphi 2010+)